# NuGet not adding reference to dll in project

Tags: nuget

I have a solution with about 5 projects including a Silverlight client.

Through NuGet, I add the Async Targeting Pack for VS 11 at the solution level and select all projects.

It adds a reference in all the non-Silverlight projects, but not the SL one.  The workaround is to add the reference by hand.

Is this a failure of NuGet?  A failure of the NuGet package?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Same thing occurs with Caliburn.Micro and the SL package.

Yet if I start from a fresh clean project, it all works as expected.

I tried deleting the .nuget and package folders, and manually removing the project reference, and that seemed to clear everything out, but I still had the above issues when adding the packages back in.

Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Silverlight are you using? I noticed [the NuGet package](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack) only targets NET40, NET45 and SL5, so if you're using Silverlight 4, the reference won't be added to your SL4 projects.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce it, looks like a bug and logged an issue on Codeplex: http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2948

Comment: Thanks very much for looking into this and logging it as an issue.